# Fixing Rewrite Rules and Conditions In HTACCESS file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, conditional-statements

Well lets say I have this follow code in my htaccess file,

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^forums/([0-9]+) forums.php?category=$1 [NC]
```

I was wondering how would I, with the above code, redirect certain extensions in a url to my websites 404 page.

For instance, if this link `mywebsite.com/forums` has any extension at the end of it such as .asp, .php, .html, and so forth it then would get redirected to my 404 page.

And on a quick side note how can I limit the last RewriteRule to only a certain forward slash where `mywebsite.com/forums/2` would show the page fine and anything after that certain limit such as `mywebsite.com/forums/2/so on...` would be redirected to my 404 page.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question properly, then you need to firm up the regular expressions to only match the patterns you really want - at the moment, they're a bit too lenient for your needs.

For example:

`RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ $1.php`

This will match anything without a trailing slash, whereas if you wanted to restrict it to only match, say, things without a trailing slash and consisting of alphanumeric characters, then you might do this:

`RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ $1.php`

(You could achieve the same effect for certain extensions only by using a lookahead assertion, but that complicates your regular expression. I feel it's probably saner (and easier on the mind) to think about the patterns you really want matched, and then express those up-front.)

Likewise, your latter example:

`RewriteRule ^forums/([0-9]+) forums.php?category=$1 [NC]`

will match anything which starts with the string **forums/**, followed by one or more digits, whether or not there's anything after that. Adding an end anchor ($) as you have above

`RewriteRule ^forums/([0-9]+)$ ...`

will assert that the string ends after the digits.

This relies on the fact that if **mod_rewrite** can't find a match, it won't attempt any rewrites, and will (in the absence of any explicit resource at that path) fall through to Apache's 404 handling, which is then up to you to override.

Comment: Very good explanation on all of this - ha did not even realize how simple of an answer the second question had. You understood perfectly by the way. Thanks.